# Reading new line in perl

Tags: perl, newline

I have created a file using:

```
open OUT, ">$outfile";
print OUT "$file_in;$system_in;$symbol_in;$price_in\n";
```

and trying later to read from this file:

```
open DATAIN, "<", "$outfile" or die $!;
while(<DATAIN>)
{
    chomp($_);
    my @ld = split(/\;/,$_);
    my $system = $ld[1];
    my $file = $ld[0];
    ...

    print "HELLOOO?$file\t$system\..";
}
```

but in the first iteration, it gives me this error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference
```

The problem is really in the \n
with which I created the new lines in the file that I am trying to read afterwards.

I tried with \r too, the error is not there, but then it reads all as one line.

Any help please? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Full code:**

```
open OUT, ">$outfile";
print OUT "$file_in;$system_in;$symbol_in;$price_in\n";

open my $fh, "<", "$outfile" or die $!;
while(<$fh>)
{
    chomp;

    my @ld = split(/\;/);
    my $system = $ld[1];
    my $file = $ld[0];
    my $symbol = $ld[2];
my $price = $ld[3];

    my $key = $file . $symbol;

    print "HELLOOO?$file\t$system\t$symbol\t$price\n"
}
```

Error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at C:/Perl/lib/Math/BigInt/Calc.pm line 476, <fh> line1.
```

The error is when it reads the line from the file. If in the initial file I put `/r` instead of `/n`, I don't get this error, but all the file is read as one line.

Comment: sorry I pasted wrong code from the various iterations, but it is not there the problem

Comment: The error is in `Math::BigInt::Calc`? Again, you are not showing us all the code. Try installing `Carp::Always` and run your program as `perl -MCarp::Always script_name ...` to get a full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the `<>` operator incorrectly.

You should not be using the filehandle `DATA`.

You should use lexical filehandles.

You do not need to pass `$_` to `chomp` or `split`.  That's why `$_` exists.

Here's how you want to do it.

```
open my $fh, '<', $outfile or die $!;
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @ld = split(/\;/);
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, it didnt work. I get again the error: Cant use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference

Comment: @martini You cannot get that error with the code you have posted. Check the line number of the error and be sure to have that exact line in the code you post.

Comment: I have no idea where in your code that applies to.  You are not showing us your entire code.  Without seeing all the code and what line the error refers to, we are guessing.  I guarantee you that your code that you originally posted is wrong.